# URL Rewriting Postback with ViewStateMac Enabled

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, url-rewriting, postback, viewstate

Using: Visual Studio 2010 with ASP.net 4.0

I have a website which uses URL rewriting and I want to keep the rewritten URL on Postback. I've read a lot of the topics on this subject and I still haven't been able to figure out if this is possible.

For example:

```
http://localhost/ActualPage.aspx?PageID=4
```

Is rewritten as:

```
http://localhost/member/forum.aspx
```

The page contains a number of controls which use a Postback (for example a Telerik RadGrid with sorting and paging). Normally when the postback takes place the browser is redirected to the unrewritten url - the address bar shows `/ActualPage.aspx?PageID=4` etc. In this scenario everything works correctly.

However I want to retain the rewritten URL after the postback, so I have coded to change the `Form.Action` property to be the rewritten URL like so:

```
Page.Form.Action = "/member/forum.aspx"
```

Now the page correctly retains the URL in the address bar but throws a `"Validation of viewstate MAC failed" error` when the postback occurs - which I would expect it too as the viewstate originated from a different URL.

Strangely this problem occurs even when `enableViewStateMac` is set to false (either in the page or in the `web.config`) - but I don't want to disable this anyway.

Effectively I think what I need to do is tell the page / viewstate mac authorisation that is it ok to accept input from this alternative URL but I can't find anyway of doing this. I've tried different URL rewrite system to see if that makes a difference, and i've tried added a generated machineKey - neither of which has made any difference. Is there any way of doing this?

In short I want:

- Rewritten page with postback going to the rewritten URL
- ViewStateMac enabled
- No viewstate validation errors

I remember in earlier versions of .NET using a `.browser` file with `FormRewriterControlAdapter` but this doesn't seem to make any difference in .NET 4 (I don't remember if it successfully retained the URL anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution - it turns out the problem was actually unrelated and masking itself as a ViewStateMac issue.

Previously I had been redirecting all the URLs to one page, doing a database lookup and then using Server.Transfer() to deliver the correct page to the browser. The real problem was being caused by using Server.Transfer() - which it seems is recognised by Microsoft to be an issue when working with the viewstate.

I have made adjustments so IIS performs the database lookup, the entire rewrite and therefore Server.Transfer() is not used - and the original problem I had has been resolved.